# Call to update local storage returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-context

In my React app, I'm storing an array of community issues in local storage upon logging in to the application.  But when I try to add another community issue to the list and update local storage, the result is undefined.

Here is my Issue Context config...:

```
function IssueProvider({ children }) {
  const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
  const [issueState, setIssueState] = useState(issues);

  function setIssueInfo({ issues }) {
    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
    setIssueState(issues)
  {
}
```

...and here is the function that is utilizing the Provider:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  const { data } = await <my axios request>

  issueContext.setIssueInfo(data);
  history.push(`profile`);
}
```

The funny thing is, when I login and fetch those issues, they're successfully logged to local storage.  But when I try to update by adding a new community issue, the value in local storage returns undefined.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: There is a bracket missing here.

const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues');

can you post the exact code or specific line where you got the problem

Comment: your explanation is not enough to give an ansswe

Answer (score 0):

const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues');

A closing bracket is missing in above line. Is this the issue you are facing. Can you elaborate where exactly you face the issue.

const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  Just edited that so it's correct as you see it now.  My error is coming from the line with the useState hook.